Ошибка при импорте comtypes.client
При выполнении import comtypes.client появляется ошибка:

[WinError -2147417850] Изменение режима для потока после его установки
невозможно

При этом если делать import comtypes то такой ошибки нет. Как можно избежать ошибки импорта чтобы использовать comtypes?
